# Remove extra = (equals to ) symbol from raw email content (which are not user inputs)

Tags: java, email, outlook

I have a java function which reads a raw email content and parses it to get the text content. The emails I send from outlook contains these extra = symbols.

> What is Lorem Ipsum?
>
> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. = Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
>   ever since the 1500= s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
>   and scrambled it to make a=

Something like this. How can I get the email content without these ?

```
private static String getTextFromMessage(MimeMessage message) throws IOException, MessagingException {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        IOUtils.copy(message.getInputStream(), writer, "UTF-8");
        String s = writer.toString();
        return s;

}
```

**I am not looking for how to remove = from a normal string. I want to remove the extra characters added by outlook and retain the user input string as it is**

Comment: Please specify when the user will be adding '=' by himself. If he will be sending an arithmetical expression, then please edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple replace method.

```
String x = "What is = Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. = Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500= s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a=";

System.out.println(x.replace('=', Character.MIN_VALUE));
```

Comment: My question is not how to remove a symbol from a string. I am reading raw email content and , for those which comes from outlook there are extra = symbols getting appended. I want to remove those, I can't blindly remove all = symbols , if user had entered it manually that should not be replaced.

Comment: Do you know what are the conditions that make those extra = signs come int the input.

Comment: Any email sent from outlook with a paragraph is having these. https://askleo.com/why_does_my_email_sometimes_show_up_with_funny_characters_like_0d_in_it/  https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/606 something similar to this

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you go through the [string manipulation concepts](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bidv1221/desktop/BIDVD/GUID-BBA975C7-B2C5-4C94-A007-28775680F6A5.htm#BILUG685) first, before asking questions that are actually quite simple.

You can use replace like this:

```
String s = writer.toString();

s = s.replace("=", "");

return s;
```

Comment: My question is not how to remove a symbol from a string. I am reading raw email content and , for those which comes from outlook there are extra = symbols getting appended. I want to remove those, I can't blindly remove all = symbols , if user had entered it manually that should not be replaced.